# How to get text from selected line in ListBox (c#)?

Tags: c#

I want to get data from selected line in List Box. I use command:

```
string selected = ListBox1.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
```

But the result is:

```
ListVievItem: {here is correct value}
```

What should i do with this: "ListVievItem: {}"

Comment: I find it strange, because a) the code should work with a `ListBox` and b) an item in a ListBox is not a `ListViewItem`. I'm guessing you are using a ListView, not a ListBox.

Comment: Also... Why SelectedItems[0] are you allowing multi select but only using the first item of the array of retrieved items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** As suggested by John Willemse, `ListBox` can't have `ListViewItems` so it seems like this question relates to `ListView` rather than to a `ListBox` so the code in the answer is changed accordingly.

When you call it like this `listView1.SelectedItems[0].ToString();` you are actually calling the `ToString()` method of the `ListViewItem` object which gives the unwanted result (first prints the class name and then the value). Each `ListViewItem` object has `Text` property from which you can get its text.

```
string selected = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
```

Comment: A ListBox does not have ListViewItems... He is confusing a ListBox with a ListView.

Answer (score 2):

```
string urItemText = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.listbox_properties(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
string selected = ListBox1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you Try just: `ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value`